# Gomod athens unable to download private repo dependency getting 404 not found in gitlab pipelines

Tags: go, gitlab, pipeline, google-app-engine-golang, athens

original error:
go: downloading gitlab.ea.com/group/repo v1.0.0
tools/buildhelper/main.go:20:2: gitlab.ea.com/group/repo@v1.0.0: reading http://gomods-athens-cc.cicd-maintenance-28024-production.svc.cluster.local/gitlab.ea.com/group/repo/@v/v1.0.0.zip: 404 Not Found
make: *** [deployment/gitlab-ci/build_all.make:22: prepare] Error 1

while other non private dependencies are getting downloaded